# Установка обработчика на элементы появившиеся после загрузки DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

такая задача, есть элементы, которые добавляются на страницу после загрузки страницы, например это элементы <div>, добавляются с помощью jQuery. Нужно сделать что бы при наведении на них выполнялось некое действие, делаю так:

```
$(document).on('hover','.container-comment',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+id).find('.comment-opt').slideToggle(250);
});
```

но hover не работает с on, может что то посоветуете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hover вроде нет такого события, есть `mouseenter, mousemove, mouseleave`

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.ajax__content__el', function(){

    $(this).css('color','red');

}).on('mouseleave', '.ajax__content__el', function(){

    $(this).css('color','black');

});
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/DcnD6/

Да ещё немного смущает ваша конструкция:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$('#'+id).find('.comment-opt').slideToggle(250);
```

я думаю хватило бы такого:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.find('.comment-opt').slideToggle(250);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, действительно можно просто написать $(this).find('.comment-opt').slideToggle(250);